# dangerous to use takeown to access dirs on external drive?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, external-hard-drive

i need to back up a few hundred gigs of data from a hard drive which is the C drive for another Windows 10 machine.

Right now the Windows 10 machine is not booting (it's definitely a hardware problem and luckily under warranty).

Using another laptop, i want to backup my user data to another drive on a second laptop. When i connect the drive from Machine 1 via usb enclosure, i get the message, "You currently don't have permissions to access. Click continue to permanently get access."

Unfortunately, doing that just causes the desktop to hang without changing anything.

i have read about the 'takeown' command and think it will solve my problem.

But i am afraid that when this drive is reinserted into the system after the hardware is repaired, any takeown command will negatively desktop permissions on my C-drive after i reattach it.

If i run the takeown command to gain access, what settings would be safest for preserving permissions when the C drive hard drive is reinsert to my  machine.

(My guess is that the problem withe the main machine may be with videocard, bad RAM, mobo or cables or CMOS. i don't have any reason that data on the hard drive has been damaged in any way. After the technician fixes my machine, i assume that my C-drive will work like normal.  i assume that I will just re-insert my original hard drive into it.

Remember that the hard drive itself is not the problem. I can see it on mysecond  Windows 10  laptop; I just can't access, browse or copy those files.

I would appreciate your suggestions about the best course to take.

Comment: You can add your current user account to the permissions for the C drive, but it is messy, use advice from Chico3001.

Comment: Dangerous? No. But you will replace the original owner.If you want to put the drive back in another desktop and boot windows 10 again you might run into problems. Chico's option of ignoring NTFS permissions by not using windows or adding another (local to **your** setup) user with read permission might be better.

Comment: @Hennes that is the messy part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the original question and I wanted to describe how I solved the problem.

Originally I had wanted a Windows-only solution, so I had not considered doing everything in Linux. That was not a bad idea -- unfortunately my linux box had died a month ago, so it was not convenient for me to do except with a Live USB. I initially tried setting up the mount points with that, but I was getting something wrong and still couldn't get read only access to that drive. Possibly I could have figured it out with more time.

I tried again in Windows. This time I took a different strategy. I opened a power shell using the Admin account. This allowed me to read and edit any directory on the old drive. (Perhaps if I opened up Win Explorer using the Admin account, I could have done the same thing).

Using the Administrator command line, I was about to copy from the External hard drive to the local Documents directory. To my surprise, after the admin user copied the files into  **C:\Users\Robert\Documents\1b**  the Robert account had full control over these files.

This solution turned out to be a LOT easier and less destructive than any solution involving the takeown command.  That is why I am marking my own answer the "correct" one even though the linux solution wasn't bad either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux live USB, you can boot from there and mount the disk, then plug your USB disk and start copying everything, W10 will surely have the fast boot option on but you can still mount the NTFS disk in read only mode

https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal

Comment: Linux= Screw windows permissions...lol.

Comment: He wants to backup his data, in readonly mode linux wont change anything on the NTFS disk

Comment: To be safe he even could mount it RO

Comment: @Chico3001 i get that, I was just enjoying how Linux ignores Windows permissions for access and copying, which makes life easy.

Comment: I'm not opposed to booting into ubuntu via CD or usb  and doing the file operations in linux (especially because it's read-only). It's been a while since I've  done mounting in linux -- especially because the second laptop does not actually belong to me.I'd prefer a Win only solution, but if I don't see one presented i think the linux usb is the best answer